# CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using this code in `UITouches Moved`, to draw image.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myimage.frame.size);

[myimage.image drawInRect:myimage.frame];

CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coloredImage.png"]].CGColor);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);

CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);


CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), previous.x, previous.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
myimage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
previous = touchLocation;
```

Here i need to make a ALERT when user fully draws the image... i.e, i have an pattern image as `myimage` and `coloredImage` is the image which draws over the `myimage` when user touches. How can i find out whether the user finished drawing the image?

Comment: first i will have an apple image which has NO COLOR, in my case that is myimage, the coloredImage is the image contains RED COLOR in apple, when user touches across the myimage the coloredimgae gets drawn, i need to make a alert when user fully draws the coloredImage over the myimage..